# ZF2 view script path generation

Tags: zend-framework2

The ZF2 [tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html) puts the view scripts into module/Album/view/album/album and it says "stored in our module’s views directory within a directory named after the controller".

The controller is AlbumController so that must be one of the 'album'-s. But where does the other 'album' come from?

I have tried to debug the framework to figure this out, but with all this magic calls and triggered events I got lost completely in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default structure is:

```
 view/[module]/[controller]/[action].phtml
```

As you have an Album Module, and an Album Controller, your views would go into that directory.

if you have an action named indexAction then your view would be called index.phtml

Comment: Thanks! Why the module is needed twice? We are already in the Album directory. Is it possible to use view/[controller]/[action].phtml instead?

Comment: that would be a bad idea, imagine you have 5-6 modules, they may all have an IndexController with an indexAction, the templates would then clash :)